# Why is the DbContext closing before I attempt this LINQ query in Entity Framework using FindAsync()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, async-await

I'm on a team using an EF, Code-first approach with ODP.Net (Oracle).   We need to attempt to write updates to multiple rows in a table, and store any exceptions in a collection to be bubbled up to a handler (so writing doesn't halt because one record can't be written).  However, this code throws an exception saying

> System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

I'm not sure why.  The same behavior occurs if the method is changed to be a synchronous method and uses `.Find()`.

```
InvModel _model;

    public InvoiceRepository(InvModel model)
    {
        _model = model;           
    }

    public void SetStatusesToSent(IEnumerable<Invoice> Invoices)
    {


        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (var id in invoices)
        {
            try
            {                    
                var iDL = await _model.INVOICES.FindAsync(id);/*THROWS A DBCONTEXT EXCEPTION HERE*/
                iDL.STATUS = Statuses.Sent; // get value from Statuses and assign                   
                _model.SaveChanges(); //save changes to the model
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
                continue; //not necessary but makes the intent more legible
            }
        }
     }
```

Additional detail update:  `_model` is injected by DI.

Comment: Because *the code closes it*, either directly or indirectly. You haven't posted where the DbContext instance is created, whether `_model` is a static field, an instance injected by DI or a singleton that was closed. The error you posted only happens when you try to use a DbContext instance after it was closed.

Comment: _model is injected by DI.

Comment: And? Is it a Singleton perhaps? What application is this? Web app? Desktop? How was it registered? Are you calling it in an action or background service?

Comment: A DbContext is a short-lived object that acts as a Unit-of-Work. In a web app, it's closed automatically once a request is processed. This way, any pending changes get discarded without requiring an extra transaction and an open connection. If you try to use that DbContext (or any other scoped context) outside the scope they were defined in, you'll end up with an `ObjectDisposedException` or an error like the one you posted

Comment: No.  The _model is actually used with no issue in several other methods in the same class, with some adding a range of invoices  to the INVOICES table.  Only the fetching of the invoice in this case is throwing the error.

Comment: Post your code. The code has a bug. That's the only way to get such an error - try to use the DbContext after it was closed

Comment: BTW you haven't posted the *actual* exception either, just part of the message. Post the actual *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This includes the location where the error was thrown and the stack trace that shows which function calls resulted in that exception. This will show you why and when the exception occured. You may find you used eg an `async void` method that was still executing when the request ended and the DbContext was disposed

Comment: The code has another *serious bug*. Calling `SaveChanges` in a loop isn't just redundant, it breaks the Unit-of-Work behavior. The first call may even do 142 DELETEs as well, if any are pending.  DbContext caches *all* pending change and persists **all** of them in a single batch, using a single internal transaction. You should execute `SaveChanges` only once, outside the loop. What you do now is at least N times slower than the normal operation.

Comment: Worse, if anything goes wrong, you'll end up with half-saved modifications unless you add an explicit long-lived transaction. This can easily lead to blocking and result in far worse delays than just N. The exclusive locks taken when the first entity was updated will remain active until the entire transaction completes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `A DbContext is a short-lived object that acts as a Unit-of-Work. In a web app, it's closed automatically once a request is processed`. Am I understood correctly that once server will rerurn response to the client, then `DbContext` will close SQL connection?

Comment: The DI will dispose the DbContext instance it created. This gives you transaction-per-request/Unit-Of-Work behavior without a transaction. There's no open connection to close. DbContext is *dis*connected until it needs to load data or persist changes. Disconnected operation and optimistic concurrency are a HUGE scalability boost introduced in the late 1990s (think 100x-1000x). ADO.NET (and every library built on top) works primarily in a disconnected mode

Answer (score -1):

Remember that LINQ executes lazily - that is when you actually use the information.
The problem might be, that Your DbContext has gone out of scope...

Use **.ToList()** or **.ToArray()** to force execution at that time.